# Wildcard symbol % does not work as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, wildcard

I have a string in a column in SQL Server table:

```
30,36,40,41,42,52,62,63,66,67,76
```

As you see, this string has number 62 and number 66.

I am using this regex to match this string:

```
%62%76%
```

But it does not match this string.

How do I need to change this Regex to match the mentioned string?

The part of SQL code:

```
WHERE 
    (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), TagID)
                   FROM ItemTag
                   WHERE ItemID = nt.ItemID
                   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS tags) LIKE '%62%76%'
```

Very strange, but when I am using `%30%52%`, it match the string, but when I am using `%30%62%`, there is no match.

Comment: Please show your actual SQL.

Comment: it seems to not match % to end or beginning of a string, which is unusual. Which engine are you using? Microsoft SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `ORDER BY TagID` to ensure the TagID values are ordered as needed for the `LIKE` expression:

```
WHERE (SELECT STUFF(
  (
    SELECT ',' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), TagID)
    FROM ItemTag
    WHERE ItemID = nt.ItemID
    ORDER BY TagID
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ), 1, 1, '') as tags
) LIKE '%62%76%'
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a crazy way to try to see if two values in are in the set.  Instead:

```
where exists (select 1
              from ItemTags it
              where it.ItemId = nt.ItemId and
                    it.tagid = 62
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from ItemTags it
              where it.ItemId = nt.ItemId and
                    it.tagid = 76
             );
```

Why would I use an adjective like "crazy" (which I do not actually mean in a literal, clinical sense)?

- There is no need to convert an integer to a string for such a comparison.
- There is no need to use functionality such as XML for such a comparison.
- `EXISTS` should be quite efficient, particularly with an index on `ItemTags(itemId, tagId)`.
- `LIKE` simply should not be used for integer comparisons.